# Is the sum and product of consistent estimators consistent?

Tags: consistency

If $T_n$ is consistent for $T$ and $U_n$ consistent for $U$, is $T_n + U_n$ consistent for $T+U$?

Secondly, is $T_n/U_n$ consistent for $T/U$?

I am looking for a reference for these facts, if they are true.

Comment: These are a direct consequence of [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem). See for example the discussion of it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_estimator#Establishing_consistency).

Comment: @Glen_b the convergence in distribution there confuses me. Don't we require convergence in probability for consistency?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables#propB1

Comment: Are you sure? I cannot find anything related to your statement in Chung's book.

Comment: I always think of this in terms of the continuous mapping theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly the sum of consistent estimates are consistent.  Regarding the ratio there is a need to specify that $U_n$ does not converge 0.

These results can be found in most advanced probability books including K. L. Chung's, or at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem).